# can't figure out how does the memory leak happen in my karatsuba implementation

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, valgrind

so my code is supposed to be implementing karatsuba algorithm for multiplication.
this is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


/* karatsuba's algo:
you have 2 numbers x,y
you halve each of them
a = 1st halve of x
b = 2nd halve of x
c = 1st halve of y
d = 2nd halve of y
n = number of digits of the biggest number if it's odd then it is decremented by 1
id n is odd then a and c take a bigger part than b and d respectively.
if number of digits of both numbers are different we shift as in concat zeros to the right of the lowest by the difference of the number of digits between them
1) kar(a, c) ---> f
2) kar(b, d) ---> s
3) kar(a+b, c+d) -> t
4) f - s - t --> Fourth
5) shiftleft(f,n) + s + shiftleft(Fourth, ceil(n/2) ) 

*/
typedef unsigned char u8;


void trim_left_zeros(u8* x)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; x[i] == '0'; i++){}
    u8* temp = (u8*) malloc(sizeof(u8)* strlen(x) + 1);
    strcpy(temp,&x[i]);
    strcpy(x,temp);
    free(temp);
    if(strlen(x) == 0)
    {
        strcpy(x,"0");
    }
}

void init_zeros(u8* x, int len)
{
    strcpy(x,"0");
    for(int i = 1; i < len; i++)
    {
        strcat(x,"0");
    }
}


void shift_r(u8** x, int amount)
{

    u8* zeros = (u8*)malloc(sizeof(u8)* (amount +( strlen(*x)) + 10));
    *x = (u8*)realloc(*x, (amount + (strlen(*x)) + 10));

    if(zeros == NULL)
    {
        printf("not allocating\n");
        return ;
    }
    init_zeros(zeros, amount);
    strcat(zeros,*x);

    strcpy(*x,zeros);
    free(zeros);

}

void shift_l(u8** x, int amount)
{

    u8* zeros = (u8*)malloc(sizeof(u8)* (amount +( strlen(*x)) + 10));
    *x = (u8*)realloc(*x, (amount + (strlen(*x)) + 10));
    if(zeros == NULL)
    {
        printf("not allocating\n");
        return ;
    }
    init_zeros(zeros, amount);
    strcat(*x,zeros);
    free(zeros);

}

u8* add(u8* a, u8* b)
{
    u8* x = (u8*) malloc(sizeof(u8) * (strlen(a) + 1));
    u8* y = (u8*) malloc(sizeof(u8) * (strlen(b) + 1));
    strcpy(x,a);
    strcpy(y,b);
    int diff_num_of_digits = 0;
    if(strlen(x) != strlen(y))
    {
        diff_num_of_digits = strlen(x) - strlen(y);
        if(diff_num_of_digits < 0)
        {
            shift_r(&x,diff_num_of_digits * -1 );
        }
        else
        {
           shift_r(&y,diff_num_of_digits); 
        }
    }
    shift_r(&y, 1);
    shift_r(&x, 1);

    int n = strlen(x);
    u8 result[n + 1];
    result[n] = '\0';

    u8 carry = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        result[i] = carry + (x[i] - 48) + (y[i] - 48);
        carry = 0;
        if(result[i] > 9)
        {
            carry = result[i] / 10;
            result[i] = (result[i] % 10) + 48;
        }
        else
        {
            result[i] += 48;
        }
    }

   
    u8* z = (u8*) malloc(sizeof(u8) * (n + 1) );
    if(result[0] == '0')
    {
        strcpy(z,&result[1]);
        free(x);
        free(y);
        return z;
    }
    strcpy(z, result);

    return z;
    
}


void borrow(u8* x,u8* res ,int index)
{
    if(res[index - 1] == 0)
    {
        borrow(x,res, index - 1);
        res[index - 1] -= 1;
        res[index] += 10;
        x[index] += 10;
        return;
        
    }
    else
    {
        res[index - 1] -= 1;
        res[index] += 10;
        x[index] += 10;
    }
    return;
}

u8* sub(u8* temp_bigger, u8* temp_smaller)
{
    u8* smaller = (u8*) malloc(sizeof(u8)* (strlen(temp_smaller) + 1));
    u8* bigger = (u8*) malloc(sizeof(u8)* (strlen(temp_bigger) + 1));
    strcpy(bigger,temp_bigger);
    strcpy(smaller, temp_smaller);
    u8* res;
    if(strcmp(bigger,smaller) == 0)
    {
        res = (u8*)malloc(sizeof(u8)*2);
        strcpy(res, "0");
        return res;
    }
    if(strcmp(smaller,"0") == 0)
    {
        res = (u8*)malloc(sizeof(u8)* strlen(bigger));
        strcpy(res, bigger);
        return res;
    }
    int diff_num_of_digits = 0;
    if(strlen(bigger) > strlen(smaller))
    {
        diff_num_of_digits = strlen(bigger) - strlen(smaller);
        shift_r(&smaller, diff_num_of_digits);
    }
    int n = strlen(bigger);
    u8 result[n+1];
    result[n] = '\0';
    int carry = 0;
    int i;
    for(int i =0; i < n; i++)
    {
        result[i] = 0;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(bigger[i] >= smaller[i])
        {
            result[i] = bigger[i] - smaller[i];
        }
        else
        {
            borrow(bigger, result, i);
            result[i] = bigger[i] - smaller[i];
        }
        
    } 
    res = (u8*)malloc(sizeof(u8)*(n+1));
    for(int i =0; i < n; i++)
    result[i]+=48;
    trim_left_zeros(smaller);
    strcpy(res, result);
    trim_left_zeros(res);
    free(bigger);
    free(smaller);
    return res;
}

u8* kar_mul(u8* a, u8* b)
{
    
    u8* x = (u8*) malloc(sizeof(u8) * (strlen(a) + 1));
    u8* y = (u8*) malloc(sizeof(u8) * (strlen(b) + 1));
    strcpy(x,a);
    strcpy(y,b);
    static int counter = 0;
    counter++;

    if(strcmp(x,"0") == 0 || strcmp(y,"0") == 0)
    {

        u8* result = (u8*)malloc(sizeof(u8) * 2); 
        strcpy(result,"0");

        free(x);
        free(y);
        return result;

    }


    int x_len, y_len,n1;
    x_len = strlen(x);
    y_len = strlen(y);
    n1 = x_len + y_len;
    if(x_len == 1 && y_len == 1)
    {
        u8 mul = (x[0] - 48) * (y[0] - 48);
        int n = mul >= 10? 3:2;
        u8* result = (u8*)malloc(sizeof(u8) * n);
        result[n-1] = '\0';
        for(int i = n-2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            result[i] = (mul % 10) + 48;
            mul = mul / 10;
        }
        free(x);
        free(y);
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        int n;
        int amount_of_shifting = x_len - y_len;
        n = x_len;
        if(amount_of_shifting > 0)
        {
            n = x_len;
            shift_r(&y, amount_of_shifting);
        }
        else if(amount_of_shifting < 0)
        {
            n = y_len;
            shift_r(&x, amount_of_shifting * -1);
        }
        u8* a,*b,*c,*d;
        a = (u8*)malloc(sizeof(u8) * ((n/2) + 2));
        b = (u8*)malloc(sizeof(u8) * ((n/2) + 2));
        c = (u8*)malloc(sizeof(u8) * ((n/2) + 2));
        d = (u8*)malloc(sizeof(u8) * ((n/2) + 2));

        if(n%2 != 0)
        {
            
            strncpy(a,x,(n/2) + 1  );
            a[(n/2) + 1] = '\0'; 
            strcpy(b,&x[(n/2)+1]);
            strncpy(c,y,(n/2) + 1  ); 
            c[(n/2) + 1] = '\0';
            strcpy(d,&y[(n/2)+1]);
            n--;
        }
        else
        {
            strncpy(a,x,n/2);
            a[(n/2)] = '\0'; 
            strcpy(b,&x[n/2]);
            strncpy(c,y,n/2);
            c[(n/2) ] = '\0';
            strcpy(d,&y[n/2]);
        }
        trim_left_zeros(a);
        trim_left_zeros(b);
        trim_left_zeros(c);
        trim_left_zeros(d);

        u8* first_step, *second_step, *third_step, *fourth_step, *final_result, *add_ab, *add_cd, *add_second_first, *term1;
        int a_len, b_len, c_len, d_len;

        add_ab = add(a,b);
        add_cd = add(c,d);

        first_step = kar_mul(a, c);

        second_step = kar_mul(b, d);
        free(a);
        free(b);
        free(c);
        free(d);

        third_step = kar_mul( add_ab, add_cd);
        free(add_ab);
        free(add_cd);

        add_second_first = add(first_step,second_step);

        fourth_step = sub(third_step, add_second_first);
        
        shift_l(&first_step,n);
        shift_l(&fourth_step, n/2);

        term1 = add(first_step,second_step);

        final_result = add(term1, fourth_step);
        free(term1);
        trim_left_zeros(final_result);


        free(first_step);
        free(second_step);
        free(third_step);
        free(fourth_step);
        free(add_second_first);
        free(x);
        free(y);
        return final_result;
    }
}

int main()
{
    u8* x = (u8*)malloc(sizeof(u8)*600);
    u8* y = (u8*)malloc(sizeof(u8)*600);

    printf("enter the first number: ");
    scanf("%s",x);
    printf("enter the second number: ");
    scanf("%s",y);


    u8* z = kar_mul(x,y);

    printf("x = %s\n",x);
    printf("y = %s\n",y);
    printf("z = %s\n",z);

    free(z);
    free(x);
    free(y);

    return 0;
}
```

my problem here is when i debug with valgrind it shows me that there is memory leak but i can't figure out how it happens, the program is doing well until the length of any of the two number reaches 4 then a memory leak occur.
here is the output of valgrind

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all  --track-origins=yes -s ./large

==42619== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==42619== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==42619== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==42619== Command: ./large
==42619== 
enter the first number: 1234
enter the second number: 3
==42619== Invalid write of size 1
==42619==    at 0x484EE8E: strcpy (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x109ABF: sub (large_int.c:180)
==42619==    by 0x10A3FF: kar_mul (large_int.c:330)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619==  Address 0x4aa8551 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==42619==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x109AA8: sub (large_int.c:179)
==42619==    by 0x10A3FF: kar_mul (large_int.c:330)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619== 
==42619== Invalid read of size 1
==42619==    at 0x484ED24: strlen (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x109498: shift_l (large_int.c:72)
==42619==    by 0x10A436: kar_mul (large_int.c:333)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619==  Address 0x4aa8551 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==42619==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x109AA8: sub (large_int.c:179)
==42619==    by 0x10A3FF: kar_mul (large_int.c:330)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619== 
==42619== Invalid read of size 1
==42619==    at 0x484ED24: strlen (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x1094C0: shift_l (large_int.c:73)
==42619==    by 0x10A436: kar_mul (large_int.c:333)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619==  Address 0x4aa8551 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==42619==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x109AA8: sub (large_int.c:179)
==42619==    by 0x10A3FF: kar_mul (large_int.c:330)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619== 
==42619== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==42619==    at 0x484EA37: strcat (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x10951F: shift_l (large_int.c:80)
==42619==    by 0x10A436: kar_mul (large_int.c:333)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==42619==    at 0x484DCD3: realloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x1094D9: shift_l (large_int.c:73)
==42619==    by 0x10A436: kar_mul (large_int.c:333)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619== 
x = 1234
y = 3
z = 3702
==42619== 
==42619== HEAP SUMMARY:
==42619==     in use at exit: 28 bytes in 4 blocks
==42619==   total heap usage: 277 allocs, 273 frees, 5,325 bytes allocated
==42619== 
==42619== 2 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 4
==42619==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x1099FD: sub (large_int.c:166)
==42619==    by 0x10A3FF: kar_mul (large_int.c:330)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619== 
==42619== 2 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 4
==42619==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x109A19: sub (large_int.c:167)
==42619==    by 0x10A3FF: kar_mul (large_int.c:330)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619== 
==42619== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 4
==42619==    at 0x484DCD3: realloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x109401: shift_r (large_int.c:54)
==42619==    by 0x109648: add (large_int.c:104)
==42619==    by 0x10A32D: kar_mul (large_int.c:313)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619== 
==42619== 12 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 4
==42619==    at 0x484DCD3: realloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x109401: shift_r (large_int.c:54)
==42619==    by 0x109659: add (large_int.c:105)
==42619==    by 0x10A32D: kar_mul (large_int.c:313)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619== 
==42619== LEAK SUMMARY:
==42619==    definitely lost: 28 bytes in 4 blocks
==42619==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==42619==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==42619==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==42619==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==42619== 
==42619== ERROR SUMMARY: 8 errors from 8 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==42619== 
==42619== 1 errors in context 1 of 8:
==42619== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==42619==    at 0x484EA37: strcat (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x10951F: shift_l (large_int.c:80)
==42619==    by 0x10A436: kar_mul (large_int.c:333)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==42619==    at 0x484DCD3: realloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x1094D9: shift_l (large_int.c:73)
==42619==    by 0x10A436: kar_mul (large_int.c:333)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619== 
==42619== 
==42619== 1 errors in context 2 of 8:
==42619== Invalid read of size 1
==42619==    at 0x484ED24: strlen (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x1094C0: shift_l (large_int.c:73)
==42619==    by 0x10A436: kar_mul (large_int.c:333)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619==  Address 0x4aa8551 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==42619==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x109AA8: sub (large_int.c:179)
==42619==    by 0x10A3FF: kar_mul (large_int.c:330)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619== 
==42619== 
==42619== 1 errors in context 3 of 8:
==42619== Invalid read of size 1
==42619==    at 0x484ED24: strlen (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x109498: shift_l (large_int.c:72)
==42619==    by 0x10A436: kar_mul (large_int.c:333)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619==  Address 0x4aa8551 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==42619==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x109AA8: sub (large_int.c:179)
==42619==    by 0x10A3FF: kar_mul (large_int.c:330)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619== 
==42619== 
==42619== 1 errors in context 4 of 8:
==42619== Invalid write of size 1
==42619==    at 0x484EE8E: strcpy (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x109ABF: sub (large_int.c:180)
==42619==    by 0x10A3FF: kar_mul (large_int.c:330)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619==  Address 0x4aa8551 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==42619==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==42619==    by 0x109AA8: sub (large_int.c:179)
==42619==    by 0x10A3FF: kar_mul (large_int.c:330)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A3B9: kar_mul (large_int.c:324)
==42619==    by 0x10A589: main (large_int.c:364)
==42619== 
==42619== ERROR SUMMARY: 8 errors from 8 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

i tried using gdb but i've just started using it and valgrind, so maybe i'm missing something that would make it easier for me to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: In the `add` function at the end you have the condition `if(result[0] == '0')`. If it's *not* true then you don't free `x` or `y`.

Comment: And Valgrind complains a *lot* about other errors as well. You probably go out of bounds. Good thing that Valgrind give you the exact locations in your source code where it happens.

Comment: And in `sub` the early `return` statements don't `free(bigger); free(smaller);`

Comment: And for your next program, please don't write large pieces of code like that without any intermediate testing. Start with an empty `main` function, build it with extra warning enabled (treated as errors), and test the program. Once it builds cleanly and passes all tests, you continue to write a *small* bit of code, that can be easily built and test. Continue like that and when you're finished you should have a working program. If there are errors (build or test) then you can easily isolate that part of the code into a [mre] for debugging.

Comment: For example in `res = (u8*)malloc(sizeof(u8)* strlen(bigger));` you would need one byte more to store the trailing `'\0'`. I get lots of compiler warnings because you use `unsigned char` (= `u8`)  instead of `char`.

Comment: I would question how much the use of string handling and dynamically allocating & freeing memory will detract from the efficiencies of using the Karatsuba algorithm. Better to allocate the memory needed at the start, once.

Comment: @WeatherVane: They will detract lots. A colleague implemented Karatsuba in Apple’s Accelerate libraries, and it only broke even against classic algorithms at very large sizes. I do not recall what the threshold was, but you have to streamline everything carefully to make it worthwhile.

Comment: @EricPostpischil indeed. I eventually managed to solve [this problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/VFMUL/) but my execution time was nowhere near as good as the best.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes you are right, thank you very much. Weird that i tried to test each function before testing kar_mul() and it was all ok, but seems i need to improve my testing skills.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks for your answers it worked out! As for the string handling and memory allocation, i thought i was doing okay with allocating once needed, maybe i got it the wrong way. Can you elaborate further on this? and what would you recommend to replace the string handling? thanks in advance

Comment: @EricPostpischil how large are we talking ?